# Form that has 2 sets of fields and does not refresh on submit

Tags: html, forms, email

I am trying to make a contact form that has 4 basic inputs to begin with:

- Name
- email
- phone number
- price amount

but then what i want to do is send the info to the admin after the user presses submit, but then loads another form on top of that page that has a second set of fields for the user to fill in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP you could just make a redirection with:

```
header("location: AnotherForm.html");
```

If you want to do it with Javascript you can show a hidden element with this:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#Form1Button").click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( "#Form2ID" ).toggle("fast");
    });
});
</script>
```

And in the `<input>` element add:

```
<input id="Form1Button" type="submit" value="Button" name="Form1Button">
```

Just make sure of 2 things:

- The second form has to be hidden with `style="display:none;"`
- The second form must contain the same CSS values (position, size) of your first form to "overlap" it.